# Leaflet antpath error "Property 'antPath' does not exist on type"

Tags: angular, leaflet, openstreetmap, polyline

I am doing a leaflet demo with angular 16. I have installed the leaflet package and it works perfectly but I can do the antpath polyline (The polyline works fine tho).

Steps I've done:

```
• npm install leaflet-ant-path 
• angular.json → scripts → "node_modules/leaflet-ant-path/dist/leaflet-ant-path.js" 
• map.ts → import 'leaflet-ant-path';
```

But this has an error:

```
Property 'antPath' does not exist on type '(latlngs: LatLngExpression[] | LatLngExpression[][], options?: PolylineOptions | undefined) => Polyline<LineString | MultiLineString, any>'.ts(2339)
```

There is no @type/leaflet-ant-path to install too.
My map.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import * as L from 'leaflet';
import 'leaflet-ant-path';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-map',
  templateUrl: './map.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./map.component.css'],
})
export class MapComponent implements OnInit {
  private map!: L.Map;

  isFullscreen: boolean = false;
  ngOnInit() {
    this.initializeMap();
  }

  private initializeMap(): void {
    this.map = L.map('map').setView([10.7769, 106.7009], 13);

    L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png').addTo(
      this.map
    );

    const antPath = L.polyline
      .antPath(
        [
          [48.43807, 2.53917],
          [10.326763, 106.326298],
        ],
        {
          color: 'red',
          dashArray: [10, 20],
        }
      )
      .addTo(this.map);
  }
}
```

angular.json

```
...
"options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/angular-16-sso-oidc",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": ["zone.js"],
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": ["src/favicon.ico", "src/assets"],
            "styles": [
              "node_modules/leaflet/dist/leaflet.css",
              "node_modules/leaflet.fullscreen/Control.FullScreen.css",
              "node_modules/@geoman-io/leaflet-geoman-free/dist/leaflet-geoman.css",
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/leaflet/dist/leaflet.js",
              "node_modules/leaflet/dist/leaflet-src.js",
              "node_modules/leaflet/dist/leaflet-src.esm.js",
              "node_modules/leaflet.fullscreen/Control.FullScreen.js",
              "node_modules/leaflet.gridlayer.googlemutant/dist/Leaflet.GoogleMutant.js",
              "node_modules/@geoman-io/leaflet-geoman-free/dist/leaflet-geoman.min.js",
              "node_modules/leaflet-ant-path/dist/leaflet-ant-path.js"
            ]
          },
...
```